# setting <hr/> tag properties (color & size) through a dialog box using javascript

Tags: javascript, plugins, ckeditor

I am looking for information to set color, and size of a hr tag through a dialogbox using javascript. is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Sure,
assign `id` to this tag to manupulate css and javascript. Example below is not tested(I just wrote it here), but gives you the whole picture. Copy-paste all code into HTML file, save it and run it

```
<div>
<a onClick="JavaScript: functionBlue()">make blue</a> <br>
<a onClick="JavaScript: functionRed()">make red</a>
</div>

<div id="hrBlock"><hr id="yourClass1"></div>
```

Then use css and create

```
<style>
  #yourClassRed
  {
   color:red;
  } 

  #yourClassBlue
  {
   color:blue;
  } 
</style>
```

and so on... read on CSS via google

When you done with your css , you can use javascript to add new elements to your DIV.

```
<script>

function functionBlue(){
document.getElementById("hrBlock").innerHTML = "<hr id=\"yourClassBlue\">";
}

function functionRed(){
document.getElementById("hrBlock").innerHTML = "<hr id=\"yourClassRed\">";
}

</script>
```

Comment: This answer would be valid only for one HR and it forces a wrapping DIV, it doesn't takes into account that the question is how to do it in CKEditor, and instead of using classes to switch states it replaces the whole HR with a new one. I guess that if anyone tries to use it, he will have to fight for quite long in order to get something that works out of it. Also, when you write an onClick attribute you don't have to specify "JavaScript: "

Comment: @AlfonsoML, maybe you are so smart and cool, but not everyone is like that. People nned to start slowly and learn now elements are replaced by another elements. When they get that they can move on with more complex things. I missed the CKEditor part, and I am not familiar with it, but I don't think it is much different in structure than any other scripting.

Comment: It seems that you also missed the part where he says that he wants to set some properties, not to replace the whole element. Just by using `.className = "blue"` and `.className = "red"` your answer would be much better and easier to understand for someone that is starting.